# all-the-cities library not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

The issue I am having is that when I require the library all-the-cities reactjs doesn't work and returns this error:

```
TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
(anonymous function)
C:myproject/node_modules/all-the-cities/index.js:6
  3 | const path = require('path')
  4 | 
  5 | 
> 6 | var pbf = new Pbf(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cities.pbf')))
  7 | 
  8 | 
  9 | console.log(pbf);
View compiled
./node_modules/all-the-cities/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:50:30
```

The library works in others nodejs projects of mine.
I tested it executing :

```
console.log(typeof fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cities.pbf')))
```

and it says its an object, I still don't understand where the issue lays.
This is the whole index.js file if you need it:

```
const Pbf = require('pbf')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')


var pbf = new Pbf(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cities.pbf')))


console.log(pbf);
var cities = []

var lastLat = 0
var lastLon = 0
while (pbf.pos < pbf.length) {
    cities.push(pbf.readMessage(readCity, {
        cityId: '',
        name: '',
        altName:'',
        country: '',
        featureCode: '',
        adminCode: '',
        population: 0,
        loc: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [0, 0] //[lon,lat]
        }
    }))
}

module.exports = cities

function readCity(tag, city, pbf) {
    if (tag === 1) city.cityId = pbf.readSVarint()
    else if (tag === 2) city.name = pbf.readString()
    else if (tag === 3) city.country = pbf.readString()
    else if (tag === 4) city.altName = pbf.readString()
    else if (tag === 5) city.muni = pbf.readString()
    else if (tag === 6) city.muniSub = pbf.readString()
    else if (tag === 7) city.featureCode = pbf.readString()
    else if (tag === 8) city.adminCode = pbf.readString()
    else if (tag === 9) city.population = pbf.readVarint()
    else if (tag === 10) {
        lastLon += pbf.readSVarint()
        city.loc.coordinates[0] = lastLon / 1e5
    } else if (tag === 11) {
        lastLat += pbf.readSVarint()
        city.loc.coordinates[1] = lastLat / 1e5
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './textFieldCity.sass';
const cities = require('all-the-cities');


class App extends Component {
  change = input => {

  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="field">
        <form id={this.props.formID}>
          <label for={this.props.inputName}>{this.props.labelText}</label>
          <input onChange={this.change} type="text" name={this.props.inputName}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it is not clear why you manually loading the database instead of following the suggested example. Did you try it? https://github.com/zeke/all-the-cities/blob/master/example.js

Comment: @MarioVernari beacouse the readme.md files says to require all-the-cities, in my other project it worked and beacouse doing as in terh example I get the error:

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve '.' in "current direcory"

Comment: the import path must be changed: my fault giving you the wrong example. Consider the snippet on the main page: import the library as `const cities = require('all-the-cities');`

Comment: @MarioVernari that's exactly what I had done in the first place, and it resulted in the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `readFileSync` is from a native node module. You can use it in the node server not in **ReactJS**. You should make an **AJAX** call to the node server from **ReactJS** code to access the methods in native node modules

Comment: Man it's a library that reads a file in its directory, I won't create a server just to access that file it would be costly and slow, is there any equivalent method in reactjs?

Comment: there are two types of libraries bro. A native node modules library implements code based on the OS in which nodeJS is installed. Reading from file system looks like a native node module library

Comment: @MarcoMolinari if your code is running in localhost, then you have a node server already. Node server is not a computer or hardware.

Comment: @AnadRaj ok I get it but now that I think about it I can't send 8mb of file to the client just for city names, the solution is to use geospace's API

Comment: @MarcoMolinari I never mentioned all-the-cities library does not work with react. It is the method readFileSync in your code I was talking about

Comment: @MarcoMolinari, you are right. Sending 8MB of data through AJAX may not be a good approach.

Comment: @MarcoMolinari I think its better if you can use restful api to give the react code only the required data through AJAX instead of all the 8MB of data

Comment: my suspect is that the actual data being transferred through AJAX would be much larger than 8MB. That's because the file itself is 8MB, but is binary. I think a possible solution is to translate the database to JSON as a separate job, then embed it to the React app with a tool like webpack.

Comment: no problem guys the source the library gets the data from is https://www.geonames.org they have a free restfull api that's suitable for my necessities so no problem

Comment: I also thought about that. If you load it as a script file, it will affect the startup time. You can also load it asynchronously to improve the startup performance